Error with -pip install pretextbook- in Git Bash
I'm new and i'm trying to learn to use PreTeXt. My first language is not English, so I apologize if I express myself wrong.
I'm following the video to install PreTeXt on my computer, but I get an error. I was wondering if someone could explain to me why I'm getting the error. The error is the next:

carlo@Carlos_ASUS MINGW64 ~
$ pip install pretextbook
Collecting pretextbook
  Using cached pretextbook-0.8.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Collecting CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached CodeChat_Server-0.2.25-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting GitPython<4,>=3 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.43-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting PyPDF2<2.6,>=2.5 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached PyPDF2-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Collecting click<9,>=8 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting click-log<0.5,>=0.4 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached click_log-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting ghp-import<3,>=2 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached ghp_import-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)
Collecting lxml<5.0,>=4.8 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached lxml-4.9.4.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pdfCropMargins<1.1.0,>=1.0.9 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached pdfCropMargins-1.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached pyppeteer-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting requests<3,>=2 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting single-version<2,>=1 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached single_version-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting watchdog<3,>=2 (from pretextbook)
  Using cached watchdog-2.3.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (36 kB)
Collecting colorama (from click<9,>=8->pretextbook)
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
Collecting bottle (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached bottle-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting cherrypy (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached CherryPy-18.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.7 kB)
Collecting CodeChat (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached CodeChat-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting json-five (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached json_five-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting markdown (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached Markdown-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.0 kB)
Collecting psutil (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached psutil-6.1.0-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (23 kB)
Collecting strictyaml (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached strictyaml-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting thrift (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached thrift-0.21.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typer[all] (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached typer-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting websockets (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached websockets-14.1-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1 (from ghp-import<3,>=2->pretextbook)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 (from GitPython<4,>=3->pretextbook)
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.11-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting wheel (from pdfCropMargins<1.1.0,>=1.0.9->pretextbook)
  Using cached wheel-0.45.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting pillow>=9.0.0 (from pdfCropMargins<1.1.0,>=1.0.9->pretextbook)
  Using cached pillow-11.0.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2.0.0,>=1.4.3 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2021 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=1.4 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached importlib_metadata-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.8 kB)
Collecting pyee<9.0.0,>=8.1.0 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached pyee-8.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.42.1 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached tqdm-4.67.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Collecting urllib3<2.0.0,>=1.25.8 (from pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (50 kB)
Collecting websockets (from CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached websockets-10.4-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests<3,>=2->pretextbook)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.4.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests<3,>=2->pretextbook)
  Using cached idna-3.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting smmap<6,>=3.0.1 (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->GitPython<4,>=3->pretextbook)
  Using cached smmap-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
Collecting zipp>=3.20 (from importlib-metadata>=1.4->pyppeteer<2.0.0,>=1.0.2->pretextbook)
  Using cached zipp-3.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->ghp-import<3,>=2->pretextbook)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting cheroot>=8.2.1 (from cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached cheroot-10.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting portend>=2.1.1 (from cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached portend-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting more-itertools (from cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached more_itertools-10.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (36 kB)
Collecting zc.lockfile (from cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached zc.lockfile-3.0.post1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Collecting jaraco.collections (from cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached jaraco.collections-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting docutils>=0.13.1 (from CodeChat->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached docutils-0.21.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.1 (from CodeChat->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting sly>=0.5 (from json-five->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached sly-0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (373 bytes)
Collecting regex (from json-five->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached regex-2024.11.6-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (41 kB)
WARNING: typer 0.13.0 does not provide the extra 'all'
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 (from typer[all]->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting shellingham>=1.3.0 (from typer[all]->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached shellingham-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting rich>=10.11.0 (from typer[all]->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached rich-13.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting jaraco.functools (from cheroot>=8.2.1->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached jaraco.functools-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting tempora>=1.8 (from portend>=2.1.1->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached tempora-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 (from rich>=10.11.0->typer[all]->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting jaraco.text (from jaraco.collections->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached jaraco.text-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting setuptools (from zc.lockfile->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached setuptools-75.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich>=10.11.0->typer[all]->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting jaraco.context>=4.1 (from jaraco.text->jaraco.collections->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached jaraco.context-6.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting autocommand (from jaraco.text->jaraco.collections->cherrypy->CodeChat-Server<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pretextbook)
  Using cached autocommand-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Using cached pretextbook-0.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Using cached click_log-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Using cached CodeChat_Server-0.2.25-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
Using cached ghp_import-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using cached GitPython-3.1.43-py3-none-any.whl (207 kB)
Using cached PyPDF2-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (200 kB)
Using cached pyppeteer-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Using cached single_version-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Using cached watchdog-2.3.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (80 kB)
Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Using cached certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl (167 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.4.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (102 kB)
Using cached gitdb-4.0.11-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Using cached idna-3.10-py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Using cached importlib_metadata-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Using cached pillow-11.0.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Using cached pyee-8.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
Using cached tqdm-4.67.0-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Using cached urllib3-1.26.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (144 kB)
Using cached bottle-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Using cached CherryPy-18.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (349 kB)
Using cached CodeChat-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Using cached json_five-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Using cached Markdown-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Using cached psutil-6.1.0-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (254 kB)
Using cached strictyaml-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
Using cached wheel-0.45.0-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Using cached cheroot-10.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Using cached docutils-0.21.2-py3-none-any.whl (587 kB)
Using cached more_itertools-10.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Using cached portend-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Using cached pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Using cached rich-13.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
Using cached shellingham-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using cached sly-0.5-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Using cached smmap-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Using cached zipp-3.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Using cached jaraco.collections-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using cached regex-2024.11.6-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (273 kB)
Using cached typer-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Using cached zc.lockfile-3.0.post1-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Using cached markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
Using cached tempora-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Using cached jaraco.functools-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Using cached jaraco.text-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using cached setuptools-75.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Using cached jaraco.context-6.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Using cached autocommand-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for lxml (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [112 lines of output]
      <string>:67: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Building lxml version 4.9.4.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectify.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\classlookup.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cleanup.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\debug.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\docloader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\dtd.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\extensions.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\iterparse.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\nsclasses.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\objectpath.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parser.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\parsertarget.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\proxy.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\readonlytree.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\relaxng.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\saxparser.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\schematron.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\serializer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xinclude.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlerror.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlid.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xmlschema.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xpath.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xslt.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\xsltext.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\src\lxml
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IC:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\include -IC:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      etree.c
      C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zpym62z5\lxml_41b9df6ce47e4a639416577623f80a97\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
      Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit0e12wous.c /Fo\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit0e12wous.obj
      xmlXPathInit0e12wous.c
      C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit0e12wous.c(1): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Failed to build lxml
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (lxml)


The first error that I got indicated that it required Microsoft Visual C++, but I already installed it and the same error continues to appear.

This work for me py -3.13 -m pip install lxml --upgrade

Apparently the video is out of date and the correct command to install it is:
pip install pretext


pretextbook declares dependency lxml<5.0,>=4.8 so pip tried lxml version 4.9.4, the latest before 5.0. That version is not compatible with Python 3.13, it provides wheels for Pythons up to 3.12 but not 3.13.
Either you compile from sources which is hard. Or use Python 3.12 or lower version.
